# vbscript how to read the url a visitor has entered from?

Tags: asp.net, html, vbscript

A page we have is visited by users from two domains. lets call them x.com and y.com

I want some of the code to only display when the user visits from y.com- how do i do this in the same vbscript file? Or do i HAVE to have separate files?

i was thinking something like

if request.SOMETHING.contains("x") then etc

Answer (score 3):

Try Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER").

You'll notice that REFERER is misspelled; that's because HTTP_REFERER was set in stone in RFC 1945 before anyone caught the spelling error.

[More info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer)

Comment: Thanks, so i just say if Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER") = "X.com"   ?

Answer (score 0):

```
request.servervariables("HTTP_REFERER")
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to checking the referer as others have suggested you could also while calling the page put a value in the url indicating where you have come from (assuming you have access to the pages you are linking from).

This is more easy for a malicious or just curious user to mess with than the http referrer so in some ways it is less reliable. However you should bear in mind that the http referrer isn't a guaranteed solution anyway (a browser might not send it, security programs might strip out the header, etc.) and that any user who manually edits things in the querystring that they shouldn't be playing with has no grounds for complaint if things stop working. As long as it won't be a security hole it should be fine. And if changing the value is a security hole you shouldn't use the referrer either since that can be easily modified by those with a mind to.